# freeform: Can I pass field's short name as admin_cc_notify parameters value

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace

I have a contact form with a few checkboxes in it. An email address is associated with each check box and if the user selects a check box and email is sent to the corresponding email id. Now I want to show these email ids in the CC of the email. I have created a text field and I append all the selected emails to the value of this text field. The text fields short name is 'recipients_list' and I gave the admin_cc_notify parameter as such:

```
admin_cc_notify="recipients_list"
```

The emails are getting sent but I cannot see the email ids in the CC of the email.

How do I get the CC to show in the email?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't use the content of a Freeform field as a Freeform parameter value. The reason is because whatever is in your field comes *after* the parsing of the Freeform tag and its parameters. It's the same reason why you can't use the value entered in a custom field in a parameter in an EE Channel Form: the Channel Form would be parse when your page is loaded, and the content in your field comes after (and too late).

Although the functionality is not exactly the same (for example, emails wouldn't be CC'ed), the recipients feature in Freeform might come in handy here: http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/form/#recipients
This would let you send notifications to email addresses selected in a checkbox list, for example.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am using the recipients feature for sending emails based on checkboxes. That works fine. I just wanted to show the selected email ids in the CC field of an email.

Comment: Is there a work around for this. Just want to show the email ids of the checkboxes selected in the CC field of the email. Using freeform tags or not. Please help.